# Are there any tournaments that treat less-represented groups preferentially?

Tags: tournament, gender

These less-represented groups could be women, transgender players, etc. As of time of writing there's only one woman in the world's top 100 players by rating, and I don't know if there's any transgender player there either.

I'm thinking in particular of tournaments where the organizers reserve some space explicitly for these less-represented groups. For example, suppose one of the 8 spots of the Candidates Tournament were reserved for the Women's World Champion, that would qualify (of course this has never happened). For the purpose of this question I exclude women-only tournaments, unless these tournaments gave special privileges to players who transitioned from male to female.

Further questions: if this has happened before, how did the community react? If this has never happened, has it ever been considered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A good amount of tournaments have prizes to the best classified women, best underage players, best unrated, best locals...

The chess community simply doesn't care too much. A few "lower-level" masters will complain about "prices for mediocrity", but no one really pays too much attention to what they say.

In many countries, the best girls in each age group from each region will have their entry fees paid for the national championship. "I don't know why" but the guys often like this!

Also, the four best men and women from each country play the Chess Olympiad every two years, whether they are grandmasters or unrated players.

Many team tournaments (more often those organized by National Federations than private ones) also include quotas on how many young/female players each team should have. As expected, teams with strong female players tend to love this rule, and "men-only" clubs often hate it!

Answer (score 8):

**Fide World Cup**

Are [qualified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_World_Cup_2019#Qualification_paths) for the World Cup:

- The Women's World Champion
- The last two World Junior Champions
- Players from Continental Championships

Answer (score 1):

All the women only events (you don't see any men only events)

Answer (score 0):

No.  Chess is a game of skill and everybody is treated equally.
Because women tend to be weaker there are some women only tournaments. But  for the other classes like you noted there is no real reason to do it, and there are not likely enough players to deserve a special tournament or even a section.

Most open tournaments   are open to anybody who signs up and pays the fees.  There may be tournaments that limit entry to certain ratings.  Most are limited to lower ratings.  A few are limited to the top players.